# How to get get a proper output with case when statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to output a table with the following columns:

```
ID|Start_date|Success|Fail
1|01-01-2010|Yes|No
2|02-01-2010|No|Yes

My table structure is the following:

Table 1: Start
ID|Start_date

Table 2: Success
ID|Success_date 

Table 3: Fail
ID|Fail_date
```

Note that when there is a Start_id, it can either result in Success or Failure but not both at the same time. The ID is unique in each table.

I wonder how we can just work with Table 1 and Table 2 to create the output format and then for the Failure column write a case statement which depend on Success (something like if Success=True, then Failure=No).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with `OUTER JOIN` ?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: How is the table Start related to the others? By id or date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take both tables into account.  It is possible that some ids are not in either table:

```
select s.ID, s.start_date, 
       (case when su.id is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as Success,
       (case when f.id is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as fail
from start s left join
     success su
     on su.ID = s.ID left join
     failures f
     on f.ID = s.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the `ID` columns are common, and there exists at most one row in `Success` table for each ID of the `Start` table, you can (left)join `Start` and `Success` tables by binding through them. There's no need for `Fail` table. And use `case..when` statements :

```
select st.ID, st.start_date, 
       case when st.start_date is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as Success,
       case when st.start_date is null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Fail
  from Start st
  left join Success sc o sc.ID = st.ID
```